# Error while migrating flask_admin to 1.5.0

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am trying to update my dependencies during this process I also update `flask_admin` from 1.0.8 to 1.5.0. But this change is giving me an issue when I deploy on production. The admin page gives me status code 500. When I look at the stack trace it looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router

    return original_handler(e)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lyftflask/__init__.py", line 187, in decorated

    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner

    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view

    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/venvs/service/trusty/service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1882, in index_view

    view_args.search, view_args.filters, page_size=page_size)

TypeError: get_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size'
```

Here are my latest dependencies:

```
flask-admin==1.5.0
flask-mongoengine==0.9.3
flask-restful==0.3.6
flask-triangle==0.5.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
flask-script==2.0.6
Flask-Assets==0.12
Flask==0.12.1
```

Based on the stack trace it looks like there is some incompatibility issue but I am not able to figure out. I tried to look into `flask-admin` release pages and I didn't notice anything.

Comment: What flask_admin model view do you use? Am I right it is flask_admin.contrib.mongoengine.view.ModelView?

Comment: @SergeyShubin yes the ModelView has changed especially the method signature: ` def get_list(self, page, sort_column, sort_desc, search, filters,
                 execute=True, page_size=None):`. Now it has extra parameter called `page_size`. I basically updated my class which extend `ModelView` and was able to fix this issue.

Comment: @Rakesh As you solved the issue you could basically add an answer yourself and accept it?